# Check if any date is older than 5 years

Tags: laravel, date, laravel-5, php-carbon

I am trying to figure out the best way to achieve something.  I am looping through some data that involves a group of dates

```
foreach ($fields['dates'] as $key => $dates) {
    $fields['dates'][$key]['datestring'] = Carbon::createFromFormat(
        'dmY',
        $dates['datestring']
    );
    var_dump($fields['dates'][$key]['datestring']);
}
```

The `var_dump` above produces something like the following

```
object(Carbon\Carbon)#330 (3) { ["date"]=> string(26) "2019-08-08 12:41:00.000000" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(3) "UTC" } object(Carbon\Carbon)#328 (3) { ["date"]=> string(26) "1987-08-08 12:41:00.000000" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(3) "UTC" }
```

So above this, I have created a variable to identify whether at least one of the dates is more than 5 years ago.  I have also created a date object for today.

```
$moreThanFiveYears = false;
$now = Carbon::now();
```

Now what I am trying to figure out is how I perform the actual check?  When I try the above, it complains because `$now` is not the same format as my other dates.  I have tried adding a format to it, but it produces only something like `20190219` and not the additional data the original dates produce.

So how can I loop all my dates to ensure at least one is greater than 5 years?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

get five years ago by `subYears()` and compare them by `greaterThan()`.

```php
$fiveYearsAgo = Carbon::now()->subYears(5);

foreach ($fields['dates'] as $key => $dates) {
    $fields['dates'][$key]['datestring'] = Carbon::createFromFormat(
        'dmY',
        $dates['datestring']
    );

    if ($fields['dates'][$key]['datestring']->greaterThan($fiveYearsAgo)) {
        $moreThanFiveYears = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I seem to get the error Call to a member function greaterThan() on string

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, had the if above the format change

Comment: The only issue I see is this.  If one date is greater than and one is less than, it still sets $moreThanFiveYears to false.  I need this set to true if any of the dates is greater than 5 years.

Comment: @katiehudson then you need to set it true and `break` the loop;

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using Carbon, you can make use of the [difference](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-difference) methods, which allow you to easily calculate the difference between two dates, in any unit:

```php
diffInSeconds()
diffInMinutes()
diffInHours()
diffInDays()
diffInYears()
```

```php
# existing date
$old = Carbon::parse("2010-01-20 12:00:00");

# current date
$now = Carbon::now();

# find the difference
$diff = $old->diffInYears($now);

# test your difference
if($diff > 5) {
  echo "date is older than 5 years";
}
```

*Note*: since you are calculating difference, the order of the comparables does not matter - the answer would be the same in both cases:

```php
$diff = $old->diffInYears($now);
$diff = $new->diffInYears($old);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try out this.

```
<?
$check_date = '2019-12-18 18:20:40';
if(strtotime($check_date) < strtotime('-5 year')){
 echo "YES";
}else{
echo "NO";
}
?>
```